# zend_translate and zend_locale

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-translate, zend-locale

Please provide me the folder strusture and code for simple small
application for zend_translate and zend_locale.

So that I will have some idea about it.
I referred framework.zend but could not understand what are the things which I should mention in controller, index, boorstrap even view. 
It seems hecic for me to work with zend_translate and zend_locale.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

To give you an example, for simple translations I have the following defined in my application.ini:

```
resources.translate.data = APPLICATION_PATH "/translations/nl/"
resources.translate.locale = "nl"
```

And inside the /translations/nl/ directory I have one or more translation files (.php, .ini, ...).

That's all you need, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am doing it,

**Bootstrap.php**

```
protected function _initTranslate()
{
    $translate = new Zend_Translate(array(
        'adapter' => 'gettext',
        'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/locale/en-US.mo',
        'locale'  => 'en'
    ));

    Zend_Registry::set('translate', $translate);
    Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translate);

    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->translate = $translate;
}
```

If I have to send a message from the controller . . I do

**AuthController.php**

```
$this->view->message = 'success';
```

And then in the view

**login.phtml**

```
if (isset($this->message)) {
    echo $this->translate->_($this->message);
}
```

The above will output the translated value of 'sucesss' from 'en-US.mo' file.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I am using:

Code for **Plugin.php**

```
    // BEGIN: Translate
    $validLang = $this->getRequest()->getParam('lang');
    $translate = new Zend_Translate('csv', 'data/lang/en.csv', 'en');
    $translate->addTranslation('data/lang/ro.csv', 'ro');
    if($validLang)
    {
        Zend_Registry::set('lang', $validLang);
        $translate->setLocale($validLang);  
    }
    else
    {
        Zend_Registry::set('lang', 'en');
        $translate->setLocale('en');
    }
    Zend_Registry::set('translate', $translate);
    // END: Translate
```

Code for **en.csv**

```
front_user_menu-wall;Wall
```

Code for **ro.csv**

```
front_user_menu-wall;Perete
```

Code for any **Zend View file**

```
echo Zend_Registry::get('translate')->_('front_user_menu-wall');
```

And some explanations:

In folder data/lang I have 2 .csv translation files. The structure is self explanatory, the semicolon (;) separates the variable name (front_user_menu-wall) from the variable value (Wall). Each variable must be placed on a new line and you can have line comments inside (ex: #this is a comment). The ro.csv file is the romanian translation file, it has the same structure, but obviously different values for the variables.

Inside Plugin.php you have

```
$validLang = $this->getRequest()->getParam('lang);
```

Zend equivalent for

```
$validLang = $_GET['lang'];
```

On the next 2 lines of code we instantiate a new Zend_Translate class using the 2 translation .csv files. Next we check if $validLang is not empty, if it's not them we set the Zend_Registry lang variable (Zend_Registry is similar with $_SESSION) with the translation file. If $validLang is empty then we default the translation to english.

If you did all the steps above, you can now echo

```
Zend_Registry::get('translate')->_('front_user_menu-wall');
```

to get the english or romanian translation.

Answer (score 0):

It's my solution:

```
protected function _initTranslate()
{
    //set gettext adapter
    $translate = new Zend_Translate('Gettext', APPLICATION_PATH . '/languages',
        null, array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME));                
    // get locale from url
    if (preg_match("/^\/([a-zA-Z]{2})($|\/)/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
        $lang = $matches[1];
    } else {
        //if locale not exsist in url - get browser locale
        $locale = new Zend_Locale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);
        $lang = $locale->getLanguage();    
    }
    if (!$translate->isAvailable($lang)) {             
         $lang = 'en';
    }            
    $translate->setLocale($lang);       
    $front = $this->getResource('FrontController');
    $front->setBaseUrl('/' . $lang . '/');        
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate); 
    $locale = $translate->getLocale();        

    $source = APPLICATION_PATH . '/languages/'.$locale.'.mo';        

    $translate->addTranslation($source, $locale);        
}
```

Comment: When providing code that solves the problem, it is best to also give at least a short explanation of how it works so that folks reading won't have to mentally parse it line by line to understand the differences.